# Moving imageview to the left makes it smaller

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

I'm having trouble moving an ImageView to the left. I have to do it every time I press a button, usually I can press it only 8 times. The problem is that on step 4 the image becomes smaller, no matter what resolution the working tablet has. 
The image size is set to the digit size from a TextView. In a 10' tablet it has 51 pixels and in a 7' one it has 36. This size is preserved until I press the button the forth time when the sizes become 26 on both devices. I am really stuck and can't figure out why is this.Maybe you can give me a hand.

Here is the xml:

> ```
>     <EditText
>         android:id="@+id/secondNumber"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_centerInParent="true"
>         android:background="#00000000"
>         android:ellipsize="end"
>         android:gravity="right"
>         android:hint="@string/second_number_hint"
>         android:inputType="number"
>         android:maxLength="8"
>         android:textSize="@dimen/number" />
>
>     <EditText
>         android:id="@+id/firstNumber"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_above="@id/secondNumber"
>         android:layout_centerInParent="true"
>         android:background="#00000000"
>         android:ellipsize="end"
>         android:focusable="true"
>         android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
>         android:gravity="right"
>         android:hint="@string/first_number_hint"
>         android:imeOptions="actionSend"
>         android:inputType="number"
>         android:maxLength="8"
>         android:textAlignment="textEnd"
>         android:textSize="@dimen/number" />
>
>     <View
>         android:id="@+id/separator"
>         android:layout_width="0px"
>         android:layout_height="0.3dp"
>         android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/secondNumber"
>         android:layout_alignRight="@+id/secondNumber"
>         android:layout_below="@+id/secondNumber"
>         android:background="#000000" />
>
>     <Button
>         android:id="@+id/nextStep"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
>         android:text="@string/next"
>         android:visibility="invisible" />
>
>     <Button
>         android:id="@+id/previousStep"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
>         android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/nextStep"
>         android:text="@string/previous"
>         android:visibility="invisible" />
>
>     <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/additionSign"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/firstNumber"
>         android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/firstNumber"
>         android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/firstNumber"
>         android:text="@string/addition_sign"
>         android:textSize="@dimen/number" />
>
>     <Button
>         android:id="@+id/newAddition"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
>         android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/previousStep"
>         android:text="@string/new_addition"
>         android:visibility="invisible" />
>
>     <ImageView
>         android:id="@+id/secondAdditionArrow"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/firstAdditionArrow"
>         android:layout_centerVertical="true"
>         android:contentDescription="@string/content_description_show_first_number"
>         android:src="@drawable/blue_arrow"
>         android:visibility="invisible" />
>
>     <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/additionMessage"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_above="@+id/secondAdditionArrow"
>         android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/firstAdditionArrow"
>         android:text="@string/addition_message"
>         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
>         android:textColor="@color/blue_arrow_text_color"
>         android:textSize="@dimen/arrow_message_size"
>         android:textStyle="bold"
>         android:visibility="invisible" />
>
>     <ImageView
>         android:id="@+id/firstAdditionArrow"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/additionSign"
>         android:layout_alignTop="@+id/additionSign"
>         android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/additionSign"
>         android:contentDescription="@string/content_description_show_first_number"
>         android:src="@drawable/blue_arrow"
>         android:visibility="invisible" />
>
>     <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/finishedMessage"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
>         android:layout_below="@+id/result"
>         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
>         android:gravity="center|top"
>         android:lines="5"
>         android:maxEms="15"
>         android:text="@string/addition_finish_message"
>         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
>         android:textColor="@color/red_arrow_color_text"
>         android:textSize="@dimen/arrow_message_size"
>         android:textStyle="bold"
>         android:visibility="invisible" />
>
>     <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/carryDigit"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_above="@+id/firstNumber"
>         android:layout_alignRight="@+id/firstNumber"
>         android:text="@string/carry_digit"
>         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
>         android:textColor="@color/green_arrow_text_color"
>         android:textSize="@dimen/number"
>         android:textStyle="bold"
>         android:visibility="invisible" />
>
>     <EditText
>         android:id="@+id/result"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_alignRight="@id/separator"
>         android:layout_below="@+id/separator"
>         android:background="#00000000"
>         android:ellipsize="end"
>         android:enabled="false"
>         android:gravity="right"
>         android:hint="@string/result"
>         android:inputType="number"
>         android:maxLength="10"
>         android:textSize="@dimen/number" >
>
>         <requestFocus />
>     </EditText>
>
>     <ImageView
>         android:id="@+id/digitKeepArrow"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_alignRight="@+id/result"
>         android:layout_below="@+id/result"
>         android:contentDescription="@string/show_addition_result"
>         android:src="@drawable/red_arrow"
>         android:visibility="invisible" />
>
>     <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/keedTheDigitMessage"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/digitKeepArrow"
>         android:layout_below="@+id/digitKeepArrow"
>         android:gravity="fill|center"
>         android:maxLines="1"
>         android:minEms="10"
>         android:text="@string/addition_message"
>         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
>         android:textColor="@color/red_arrow_color_text"
>         android:textSize="@dimen/arrow_message_size"
>         android:textStyle="bold"
>         android:visibility="invisible" />
>
>     <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/carryDigitMessage"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_above="@+id/carryDigitArrow"
>         android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/carryDigitArrow"
>         android:minEms="10"
>         android:text="@string/carry_digit"
>         android:textColor="@color/green_arrow_text_color"
>         android:textSize="@dimen/arrow_message_size"
>         android:textStyle="bold"
>         android:visibility="invisible" />
>
>     <ImageView
>         android:id="@+id/carryDigitArrow"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_above="@+id/carryDigit"
>         android:layout_alignRight="@+id/firstNumber"
>         android:contentDescription="@string/show_carry_digit"
>         android:src="@drawable/green_arrow"
>         android:visibility="invisible" />
>
> </RelativeLayout>
> ```

And the function that moves the ImageView is this:

```
  Rect bounds = new Rect();
        Paint textPaint = firstNumber.getPaint();
        textPaint.getTextBounds(firstNumber.getText().toString(), 0,
                firstNumber.getText().toString().length(), bounds);
        int width = bounds.width();


            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams position = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    arrow.getWidth(), arrow.getHeight());

            position.setMargins(
                    arrow.getLeft() - width / this.firstNumber.size(),
                    arrow.getTop(), arrow.getLeft(), arrow.getBottom());



            arrow.setLayoutParams(position);


        }
```

The dimensions xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="number">55dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="arrow_message_size">32dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

I can't post the image directly, sorry.

And the strings.xml file:

```
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">Math Tutor</string>
    <string name="title_main_activity">Math Tutor</string>
    <string name="welcome_message">Welcome to Math Tutor! Choose an operation from the left side pane to get started.</string>
    <string name="menu_title">Basic Math</string>
    <string name="addition_sign">+</string>
    <string name="solve">Solve</string>
    <string name="next">Next</string>
    <string name="previous">Previous</string>
    <string name="insert_first_number">Insert first number</string>
    <string name="first_step">First step</string>
    <string name="second_step">Second step</string>
    <string name="third_step">Third step</string>
    <string name="first_number_hint">Number 1</string>
    <string name="second_number_hint">Number 2</string>
    <string name="result">Result</string>
    <string name="new_addition">New Addition</string>
    <string name="subtraction_sign">-</string>
    <string name="number">Number</string>
    <string name="exponent">Exponent</string>
    <string name="equal_sign">=</string>
    <string name="power">Power</string>
    <string name="base">Base</string>
    <string name="content_description_show_first_number">Show first number</string>
    <string name="addition_message">Addition</string>
    <string name="show_addition_result">Show addition result</string>
    <string name="addition_finish_message">The operation is finished. Press New Addition for a new addition!</string>
    <string name="carry_digit">1</string>
    <string name="show_carry_digit">Show carry digit</string>

</resources>
```

The weird part is that I have managed with this method to move an arrow like I want to but this one just doesn't seem to want to do what I want.

**UPDATE**

I've managed to fix the resize when on step 4 but now I'm always getting the image streched when I reach step 8. Here is the updated code:

```
Rect bounds = new Rect();
        Paint textPaint = result.getPaint();
        textPaint.getTextBounds(result.getText().toString(), 0, result
                .getText().toString().length(), bounds);
        int width = bounds.width();

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams position = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                this.carryDigitArrowOriginalPosition.width,
                this.carryDigitArrowOriginalPosition.height);
        position.setMargins(this.carryDigitArrowOriginalPosition.leftMargin
                - width, this.carryDigitArrowOriginalPosition.topMargin,
                result.getRight(),
                this.carryDigitArrowOriginalPosition.bottomMargin);
```

The rest are the same. I don't understand why it stretches the image even though it has a big width. Here are 2 screens of what happens:

[Not Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mbJs.png)
[Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0YEz.png)

Comment: Can you please share your dimension and string xml?

Comment: Please share images also

Comment: I've added what you asked.

Comment: I have just used the centercrop property of the imageview and looks like it is not resizing anymore, it just cuts a bit on the edges, so I'm probably making the width a bit too small. Thanks for the help anyway!